# Recycling and reusing imageview

Tags: android, imageview

in MainActivity I set image of my Imageview Using Picasso by this code on OnCreate:

```
    ivLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backimage);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.background).fit()
            .into(ivLogo);
```

and recycle in On OnDestroy Function:

```
((BitmapDrawable)ivLogo.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
```

i HAVE to Recycle my Imageview To Avoid OutOfMemory Error.

but when i come back to this activity from another by this code:

```
        Intent it = new Intent(WorldChose.this, MainMenu.class);
        // it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(it);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);
        finish();
```

I get This Error:

```
09-19 15:04:32.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2112): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can not use a recycled bitmap**. And it seems that you are doing that. First you are recycling the bitmap, and then you are tying to use it when user come back to the activity.

From documentation:

> Caution: You should use recycle() only when you are sure that the
>   bitmap is no longer being used. If you call recycle() and later
>   attempt to draw the bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to
>   use a recycled bitmap".

[Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

*Edit: on Android 3.0 and Higher there is not so much reasons to call recycle. (Read doc)*

Comment: i want to reuse a imageview after recycling and finishing that activity, why its not possible, its same as running an activity from beginning isnt it?

Comment: You are talking about reuse ImageView, but actually the recycle method is ONLY for the bitmap.

Comment: If you recycle bitmap, that means that you are not going to use anymore until the app is completly destroyed and reopened. So what you are doing i't nos the same as running from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to your code, actually you call recycle method for the Bitmap object.

Secondly, once you recycle a bitmap, it can't be used any more, you can check the source code :

```
private void checkRecycled(String errorMessage) {
    if (mRecycled) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

This is code snippet in Bitmap source code, and it will be called firstly in most of Bitmap operation methods.

Last and not least, recycle method actually does nothing with memory recycling if the OS API level is above 11.

Comment: And you don't have to worry about OOM problem too much, especially you are using the Picasso. Because it manages to control the peak memory for you.